# How can I overlap content in Windows Movie Maker?

Tags: windows-movie-maker

Say I want to overlap another video on top of the one already playing. How do I do this? There seems to be no option to do so in the actual menus.

Answer (score 1):

There's no native support for any sort of "Picture-in-Picture" functionality in Windows Movie Maker, so unfortunately, what you are asking cannot be done in WMM.